# Google Cloud Storage: M4A audio files: Won't play in console when uploaded using gsutil

Tags: audio, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I store M4A audio files on GCS. When uploading the files manually from the GCP Console, the file type on GCS is **x-m4a** and you can click on the file and play it (if it's small enough). If I upload the same file using gsutil cp, however, the resulting file type is **mp4a-latm** and, if you click on it, GCS doesn't offer the audio player widget. The files are the same size. I run gsutil on a Mac Catalina. I'd like to use gsutil *and* play the audio in the Console. Anyone knows why the difference and how to adjust gsutil's behavior? Many thanks [Example: two different types on GCS; this is the same file on my laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqJa7.png)

Comment: For grins, after the file is uploaded, try changing the "Content-Type" on the file that doesn't work to be the type that does work.  You can use the gsutil setmeta command to achieve this.

Comment: Spot on. Thank you @Kolban! (And yes, the -h flag is well documented, my fumble)